# How to fix cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am working with the angular and ionic framework. I added a loading controller but getting the below error.

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener:error ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined

```
 loading: HTMLIonLoadingElement;
  constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController) {}

  async start(message = "Please wait") {
    this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      // spinner: null,
      // duration: 5000,
      message: message,
      // translucent: true,
      // cssClass: 'custom-class custom-loading',
      // backdropDismiss: true
    });
    await this.loading.present();
    //const { role, data } = await this.loading.onDidDismiss();
  }

  async stop() {
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Any solution appreciated!

Comment: So your `stop` method is being called before `loading` can be initialized to the element in your `start` method.

Comment: The error says, that `this.loading` is undefined in your `stop` method. You need to check for existence of that object.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur appreciate your answer. it is working. I post the answer if anybody need can check this in future

Answer (score 0):

Check loading is not undefined, before calling `stop()` function

```
 loading: HTMLIonLoadingElement;
  constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController) {}

  async start(message = "Please wait") {
    this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      // spinner: null,
      // duration: 5000,
      message: message,
      // translucent: true,
      // cssClass: 'custom-class custom-loading',
      // backdropDismiss: true
    });
    await this.loading.present();
    //const { role, data } = await this.loading.onDidDismiss();
  }

  async stop() {
   if(this.loading) { // Added this condition
     this.loading.dismiss();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're problem right now is two fold the first, you are not declaring or loading the element properly.

The easiest fix is to turn this into any, there is no such Element name HTMLIonLoadingElement - or if its an interface you should change the name of it.

you should either create an interface and bind it or wildcard this using any to see if it functions if it does then go through the type sensed list of available options which is your fastest point to resolution.

```
    loading ?: any;
    message?: any;
    start(){
      setTimeout(()=>{
        const id = document ?.querySelector('id') as HTMLElement;
        // put a wait timer of 250 milliseconds to allow for the dom to render
        // check if id exists id is your element name so change it and add #element to your html component
        if(id){
          this.loading = this.loadingcontroller.create({
            // spinner: null,
            // duration: 5000,
            message: this.message,
            // translucent: true,
            // cssClass: 'custom-class custom-loading',
            // backdropDismiss: true
          });
          this.loading ?.present();
          // this clears the possibility of the element being resolved as undefined turned into Boolean logic to check if exists
// should have cleared properly else fail it
             } else {
          // use rxjs and tell it to retry once then do error handling
          retry(1);
          // then failed logic create an error handling function
          
             }
        
        }, 250)
      
        //const { role, data } = await this.loading.onDidDismiss();
      }
    stop(){
      this.loading.dismiss()
    }
```